# Column reference is ambiguous Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I wrote this function to insert or update my subscription rows into the subscription table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_set_subscription(input_subscription_id varchar(50), input_customer_id varchar(50), input_api_key char(16), input_issued_date timestamp, input_subscription_type integer)
RETURNS TABLE (subscription_id varchar(50),
           customer_id varchar(50),
           api_key char(16),
           issued_date timestamp,
           subscription_type smallint) AS
$func$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    INSERT INTO subscription
    VALUES (input_subscription_id, input_customer_id, input_api_key, input_issued_date, inpu_subscription_type)
    ON CONFLICT (subscription_id)
    DO UPDATE SET issued_date = subscription.issued_date
    RETURNING *;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

During runtime, I am getting the following error:

```
postgres     | 2020-08-05 14:11:09.607 UTC [79] ERROR:  column reference "subscription_id" is ambiguous at character 151
postgres     | 2020-08-05 14:11:09.607 UTC [79] DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
postgres     | 2020-08-05 14:11:09.607 UTC [79] QUERY:  INSERT INTO subscription
postgres     |          VALUES (input_subscription_id, input_customer_id, input_api_key, input_issued_date, input_subscription_type)
postgres     |          ON CONFLICT (subscription_id)
postgres     |          DO UPDATE SET issued_date = subscription.issued_date
postgres     |          RETURNING *
postgres     | 2020-08-05 14:11:09.607 UTC [79] CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fn_set_subscription(character varying,character varying,character,timestamp without time zone,integer) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
postgres     | 2020-08-05 14:11:09.607 UTC [79] STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM fn_set_subscription("input_subscription_id" := $1,"input_customer_id" := $2,"input_api_key" := $3,"input_issued_date" := $4,"input_subscription_type" := $5)
```

I've tried to change the subscription_id column name in the ON CONFLICT to => ON CONFLICT(subscription.subscription_id) but it seems that I'm not allowed to do so.

Any help/improvements would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: Try `returns setof subscription` instead of `returns table (...)`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, 'returns setof subscription' actually works. Is it possible to make this work with 'returns table'? The reason is that I am using the Dapper ORM, and it auto-serializes my object to the specified class when using 'returns table'

Comment: If your ORM requires that, then change `on conflict (subscription_id)` to `on conflict on constraint <your uq constraint name here>`.  Looks like it will be the pk on your `subscription` table.

Comment: Great idea, will try it right away and I will get back to you

Comment: @MikeOrganek do you know if primary keys have some default constraint name template they follow when you don't specify them explicitly.

Comment: Inside of psql, do `\d subscription`.  Should be `subscription_pkey`, I think.

Comment: Yes you were right. I also tried binding the conflict statement to the constraint, and it worked. Thanks for the workaround. @MikeOrganek

Comment: Please don't miss @a_horse_with_no_name's `language sql` solution, below.

Answer (score 1):

One way to overcome this, is to use a SQL function, not PL/pgSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_set_subscription(
  input_subscription_id varchar(50), 
  input_customer_id varchar(50), 
  input_api_key char(16), 
  input_issued_date timestamp, 
  input_subscription_type smallint)

RETURNS TABLE (subscription_id varchar(50),
               customer_id varchar(50),
               api_key char(16),
               issued_date timestamp,
               subscription_type smallint) 
AS
$func$
  INSERT INTO subscription (subscription_id, customer_id, api_key, subscription_type)
  VALUES (input_subscription_id, input_customer_id, input_api_key, input_issued_date, input_subscription_type)
  ON CONFLICT (subscription_id)
      DO UPDATE SET issued_date = excluded.issued_date
  RETURNING *;
$func$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

---

Another possibility is to use `#variable_conflict use_column` as described in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105902) and documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#id-1.8.8.13.3.9)